# Why should only a privileged user get to see down-votes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, privileges, vote-count

Straightforward question. Why must one earn a number of reputation points before being able to see how many down-votes a particular question has? It is understandable why other features are given to users with a certain number of reputation points, such as `create tags`, or `review suggested edits`, because indeed, only a trusted user should be able to do these things, i.e someone who is serious about SO.

But I don't see any benefit of giving only privileged users the ability to see down-votes, is there some underlying reason for this, or is it simply to give people some kind of goal on SO, so as to keep them hooked or what not?

Comment: If memory serves: Mostly because it's a relatively expensive thing for the server to do.

Comment: See [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69852) on Meta SE; the score is cached in the database, the vote breakdown is not. So the query is expensive and by making this a privilege you limit the number of queries you have to run.

Comment: [Two queries are always slower than none.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007)

Comment: Interesting, definitely not the answers I was expecting.

Comment: Related: http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because the process to get vote counts is more expensive, and as such could be abused by low-rep users.

You can actually still view vote counts, however, using an undocumented function: the timeline display.

Take any question URL, eg `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284289/why-should-only-a-privileged-user-get-to-see-down-votes`.  Then, change the `questions` part to `posts`, and replace everything after the numbers with `timeline`.  So you would get [`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/284289/timeline`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/284289/timeline).

You can also use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep), which enables this functionality without the reputation limit.