# Why do we not show both the number of upvotes and downvotes for a post?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-count

Lets say there is an answer which appeals closely to two opposite schools of thoughts about a programming paradigm or practice. It attracts approximately similar number of up votes and down votes from programmers who are divided along this line of thinking.

Now the votes this particular answer would have got may be close to zero despite the fact hundreds of them has voted in favor of it or against. This effectively hides the fact that the community has opposing opinions about the answer.

Wouldn't it be more appropriate to show both up votes and down votes for every post to reflect the true response it has got from the community?

For example:

An answer, in the most simple terms, which gets 2 up votes first and a down vote  later has total of one. Now the dispute of opinion which is triggered by this answer is effectively hidden by the reader who just sees only one up vote there. This scales up and down and is hidden from the readers forever.

UPDATE
Now it has been pointed out that this information is available for privileged users, why is it not revealed to those who are not there yet? What is the advantage the community is getting by hiding their true response from some of us?

As I pointed out in some of my comments, its completely a wrong picture a user gets by seeing an answer with 13 votes when it really had 24 up votes and 11 down votes. The ordinary user who sees just the 13 votes is effectively deprived of the fact that there is something wrong in this answer.

Why is it hidden until someone reaches 1000 reputation?

Comment: you can see the up and down votes after you get some reputation

Comment: A scenario where two conflicting, legitimate schools of thought get in a battle like this seems super rare, if it exists at all. Usually, the heavily downvoted answers tend to feature programming practices that aren't just "different", they are right-out harmful.

Comment: Controversial answers tends to show up on primarily opinion-based questions, which are off-topic for the site anyways.

Comment: I don't think they are super rare. The significance of such a battle is always reflected by the proximity of the total votes showing to zero. In that sense it is virtually everywhere.

Comment: Examples, or they don't exist `:P`

Comment: :) Absence of evidence is not always evidence of absence.

Comment: @CharlieH: By that logic, every suspect is guilty until proven innocent.

Comment: If you're going to make the argument that they are not rare, you're going to have to put forward some examples.

Comment: I have given the most classic example in my update.

Comment: A total of __3__ votes is quite a different story than _"hundreds of them"_.

Comment: It is the same theory scaled up in the hundreds.

Comment: Same theory, sure. But is this actually a problem? As said before, can you link us to even _one_ example?

Comment: Well how difficult is this to understand :) Look at the picture provided in the answer. All I would have got by seeing it in my normal account is that there are 13 likes to it than disliked. Now I even don't know if there were one person thinking this answer is not good. 

But the fact hidden from me is that 24 people really liked it and 11 thought the answer was bad. I would really have known that there is something wrong in this answer if this facts were revealed to me in my normal view.

Comment: @CharlieH It's not difficult to understand at all.  You're simply being told that this is a *very* rare situation.  How hard is it to understand that this just doesn't actually happen in practice, and thus isn't a real problem?

Comment: The "proximity zero" reference I made in my question was the most extreme case of the weakness of this voting system I pointed out. Tickling down from that, the problem spreads out to almost all the questions and answers here in different scales. 

The true response of the community is simply hidden when an answer has 10, 20, or 300 votes. Who knows how many of them was against and how many in favor? It is practically happening in every question at every second here. At least that shouldn't be difficult to understand for those who say it practically doesn't happen.

Comment: If you're really _that_ concerned as to whether an answer has downvotes, there is a trick you can use: The timeline of a post. Granted, it will require some manual counting and math on your part, but it shows you votes on a question and its answers by day. To get to the timeline, change your url from `{site}/questions/{questionId}/{questionTitle}` to `{site}/posts/{questionId}/timeline`.

Comment: Very nice! But my concern is for all the users to have a better idea about what they see on their screens. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: updated question has been asked and answered in [Why should only a privileged user get to see down-votes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284293/839601)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you get 1000 reputation you become an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), one of the things this privilege unlocks is the ability to see the vote counts on posts.

> [image: Vote counts]

Your vote should not be decided based on what others think about something (that goes for things outside of SO too). You should be judging whether a post is clear, shows research effort, and is useful - the three things that are what a vote represents.

Comment: When hovering on the post's votes, you can see a tooltip saying: _"View upvote and downvote totals"_. Maybe it's an option to add a line under that, saying something like: _"Total vote count: 35"_

Comment: @Cerbrus would that make the 1k privilege little more than a display perk?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: good point. Maybe the addition should be enabled when you get to 1k.

Comment: Is there even a tooltip for under 1K users? If you can't click I'd think there isn't

Comment: The tooltip is indeed not even there if you don't have 1k rep. (Just tried it.) @Patrice