# I can't delete my own question even though the answer has a score of -1

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, help-center

According to the help center:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

I asked this (admittedly not great) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579542/devtoolsinstall-git-failed-to-connect-to-github-com). It was downvoted, put on hold, and judging by the comments and my own further investigation, I wasn't going to get an answer on SO. Seemed ripe for deletion.

However, there is one answer to the question. The answer doesn't work and has a score of -1, but I am still not allowed to delete the question. Is this a bug, an issue with documentation, or am I missing something?

For the record, I tried to delete before and after the question was put on hold. Same result.

Comment: You can't delete a question if it has at least one *upvoted* answer. Its score is irrelevant. That answer is currently at +1/-2.

Comment: In this specific case, you shouldn't worry too much because since it's closed, the Community user will probably delete it in 9 days (some things could keep that from happening, see the last bullet list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) for more information).

Comment: @vaultah How would the OP be able to know that?

Comment: @Ferrybig, The '[“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)' userscript adds seeing vote counts for anyone on all SE sites. The information is also available in the [answer's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47579674/timeline).

Comment: in fact, OP under 1000 rep can't see detailed score, for him, it's only the final score written and it is not expandable so you can't expect him to see an up-vote anywhere

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Fortunately, with an experienced usage of the SEDE you can get nearly all the infos what only 10k+ users have access to, and a lot more. Voting counts is only a single one, there are even much more. And using the SEDE doesn't require any reputation from you on any of the sites.

Comment: @peterh ... SEDE ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier https://data.stackexchange.com . The SE generously allows us to run queries on a readonly subset of their productive database. All the secret things (for example, voting data) is filtered out, but what remains is very worthy.

Comment: What a pain compared to a well developed feature that would immediately tells you what the problem is. OP should not be asked to use these tools as a workaround to see why he can't delete his question. Then again, SO developers probably has too much stuff to correct to care about this.

Comment: @peterh Remember that SEDE is not a live representation of the SO database, it lags behind by several days which means it's not useful in this case.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier To each his own. Btw, you are working hardly, months or years long, to get easy access to the information of a little subset of the data, what the SEDE contains for all the sites. I rather learned the SEDE, so I've got also an irreplaceable understand on the inner workings of the SE, and I have this on all the sites. I think for the users focused to only a single SE site may be your "business model" more preferable. I have 4 3k+ accounts and roughly 25 200+.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, it is by design.

It does not seem like you are advocating for the design to be changed, so I do not think the question is a duplicate of [Delete protection for questions with a new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310206/delete-protection-for-questions-with-a-new-answer), nor is this question [requesting that vote totals be available to all users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307243/why-do-we-not-show-both-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvotes-for-a-post).

If there is an upvoted answer, you cannot delete your question.

> ## [When *can’t* I delete my own post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/178816)
>
> You can’t delete *your own question* when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
> You can’t delete *any* of your questions or answers if you haven’t *registered* your account (that is, associated an OpenID with it).

There are numerous reasons for this to be in place, and you just happened to catch the edge case where the answer on your question had an upvote but a net negative total. Ensuring that the questions you create are high enough quality to stand the test of time will place you above many of the setbacks that edge cases present.

That said, although I am not an expert with git, of the set of `install_git` questions at Stack Overflow which were well received, yours seems to fit into that group, so I am curious why you felt it should be deleted. If your problem was simple, at the very least leave an explaining comment of what solved the problem (since the post is now closed) - perhaps there is a case for re-opening it based on what the solution was.

If there is no change in the status of the question, the roomba will get it eventually.

> The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.
>   -https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/178816

Comment: This is interesting. I am not a *reputation whore* or anything but having some rights is surely nice to have... I have had several accepted answers with over lets say 3 upvotes, and the owner of the post just deletes their question after having an answer, how have they been able to delete that question with me having a good answer?

Comment: @Tomm It wasn't deleted by the OP. It was probably deleted by three 10k users, perhaps even a moderator.