# Does visibility of new questions depend on user reputation?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, live-refresh

As a new user with little reputation, whenever I keep the [active questions link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) open in my browser, I find that I am **not** notified of active questions; I have to manually refresh the tabs in order to find them.

[image: Questions visible to me]

However, my friend who has 400+ reputation is notified of the newly active questions as below:

[image: Questions notification visible to my friend]

Given the fact that we both used the same system, with the same settings, at the same point of time (he logged in in the incognito mode), why this difference?  Due to this, by the time I hit F5 and the page is loaded, I find that the active/new questions are either already answered or edited.  Is this something that is deliberately done by SO because of the low quality answers usually posted by the new users?

**Edit:** Although this is not a critical question, I would appreciate it if some **moderator** (who has access to the backend code and functionality) sheds some light on this.

Comment: related: [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/165773)

Comment: @gnat, yes, that precisely is the feature I am talking about.  However it is an old 2012 link and this has been deployed in SO as well.  What I wonder is why I cannot see it, although websockets are enabled.  Any pointers, please?

Comment: If it is enabled at a given rep level, I'd expect it to be for performance reasons, as that feature is going to consume more system resources than not having it enabled.

Comment: @Servy, okay, so you mean to say that it is enabled at some rep level?  Could you please let me know what it is?

Comment: @CodingBatman I didn't say that at all.

Comment: Anyway...it's not a about who answers *first*...it's about who answers **best**. Just because an answer has been posted doesn't mean the answer is helpful, right or couldn't be improved upon by someone taking their time to provide a *complete* answer. Take your time...do it right. The rep will come.

Comment: I don't think this is tied to rep.It's not on the [list of privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and the [live-refresh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-refresh) tag at Meta SE shows questions from folks with very little rep. I saw one from someone with 16 points.

Comment: @BSMP It could be part of the new user restrictions.

Comment: @Servy, please excuse my grammar, but if by *new user* you mean someone who has just created an account, then well, I have been here for 3 years and 1 month!  This made me think that it must be related to reputation in the first place.

Comment: @CodingBatman No, by new user restrictions I mean the privilege, "new user restrictions".

Comment: I'm almost sure that registered users are not discriminated in the live refresh, unlike unregistered/anonymous ones. So, I just kept support and bug tags. I'm sure that is either.

Comment: @Servy, I have already earned the [New User Restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege, as my rep is greater than 10.

Comment: @CodingBatman Do you have any browser plugins that may be blocking Live Refresh? What happens if *you* login using Incognito Mode; does Live Refresh work?

Comment: I have 26k+ rep and to my memory I have never see the live reload notification on Stack Overflow, however it does work fine on other SE sties and here on Meta. I guess I always just assumed there were too many questions or something coming in for it to work. No errors in my console, just the usual deprecated warning from the ancient jQuery version that is being used.

Comment: @cybermonkey, yes, I do have plugins installed - but all those are available in the incognito mode as well.  So both my friend and I should have faced the same issue.

Comment: I actually get this too - when I'm logged in with my main account (this one) the live updates ("X new questions", new answers, votes, and new comments) work. However, with a 1 rep test account, they don't. Maybe it's a bug or it's done for performance ?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - on SO we don't have the real time question notification on the homepage or questions page (unfiltered), for exactly that reason - it is a firehose and not particularly useful. We do have it enabled on the tag pages (for active/newest sorts)

Comment: @Oded Makes sense. Now that you mention it, I have seen it on the individual tag pages.

Comment: I have over 400 rep and its hit or miss for me. Some days I get the notifications and some days I don't.

Comment: I see the meta effect has kicked in and bumped the OP up past the 30 rep threshold.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

> Does visibility of new questions depend on user reputation?

Specifically:

> I am not notified of active questions; I have to manually refresh the tabs in order to find them.

---

You are correct - we are currently only enabling realtime notifications to users with reputation of 30 and above (on Stack Overflow only) - this is something we can tune at runtime; this restriction is in place for performance and availability reasons (things like ensuring we don't hit port exhaustion on the websocket server OS, letting us control how many sockets we are handling etc...).

I am talking to the team to see if we can lower the threshold, but no promises.

Comment: It would be helpful for the new users, if this point about *live-refresh* is added in the privileges section.  Currently I am unable to see it there.  Also, it would be helpful if the threshold is lowered (but this is just my selfish personal request - decision and analysis I leave to you all :) ).

Comment: @CodingBatman - it isn't about privileges. It is specifically tied to reputation (and as I said, it tunable - it is like that only on SO, so not correct to say it is a privilege). And it wouldn't be helpful for anyone if lowering the threshold would crash our load balancers and no one could get the live-refresh (or the site itself, for that matter)...

Comment: @Oded And yet, "privileges" are, for all intents and purposes, "things unlocked by reputation above threshold". It makes sense placing a mention of it there.

Comment: @Xan - and yet, this isn't a privilege. It is a throttle.

Comment: Try seeing it from the user perspective. It's a perk for them, it's unlocked by reputation. Semantics! But I get your point - it's not a specific unlock but something you tune at any moment based on performance.

Comment: @Oded Not being throttled is a privilege here from the user perspective. But like Xan said, semantics :-)

Comment: @TylerH - it isn't a privilege because it doesn't need earning, in the general case. We do a number of special things on SO that we don't do on other sites due to performance, and this is just one of them. If we change the threshold tomorrow to 1000, would you expect us to update two privileges as well? The point of the toggle is to keep the system stable and operational, and for a nice-to-have, that's the compromise we came to.

Comment: What's the difference between this and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284289/why-should-only-a-privileged-user-get-to-see-down-votes?

Comment: @RoadieRich - privileges are set and don't usually change. They are also generally awarded at the same reputation points on all sites. This is a specific throttle that is intended to keep the systems running, not a privilege to be earned.

Comment: @Oded In the sense that once you've crossed a certain threshold of reputation (say, 30 in this case), you gain access to a feature of the site, that makes it a privilege. That it so happens to be arbitrary and not the same number for all time is irrelevant. I'm not saying it should be any different from what it is now, or that it should be listed on the Privileges page, I'm just saying that, by definition, the word privilege applies here.

Comment: @Oded but that originally applied to the up/downvote privilege surely?  The only reason *that* is a privilege (i.e. limited by rep level) is to keep systems running?

Comment: The funny thing is: I often keep a Stack Overflow browser tab open, and before doing so navigate to a page _other_ than the first page of a tag-filtered search, specifically so I _won't_ get these updates (which I've always assumed incurred some specific overhead both locally and server-side, and I hate wasting resources like that). I'd love to see a way to toggle this behavior (it could default to "off" for low-rep users, and/or the toggle could include a link to a brief explanation of why low-rep users don't get the feature).

Comment: In any case, I do agree that this undocumented feature could use some documentation. Debating whether it's really a "privilege" or not misses the point; the fact is, users trying to figure out what reputation affects, and whether it affects this, will find themselves at the reputation/privilege-related help topics, so that would seem to be a natural place to document it (even if that documentation also called out specifically that this feature is _not_ a "privilege" per se).

Comment: I expect this has changed by now, but would the number of up-voted answers not be better then rep, as people who only ask questions don't need the update?