# Add the 30-rep live updates privilege to the privileges page

Tags: feature-request, privileges, live-refresh

Currently, [30 reputation is required in order to see live updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322824/4428462) (aka realtime notifications, used for "*x new questions*" on tag pages, notifications of edits on posts and so on).

The fact that you get this only after reaching 30 rep makes it a privilege (from the user's perspective) - however, it's not listed on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Thus, **I propose that a "See live updates" privilege is added to that privileges page** to reflect the fact that live updates are only enabled after reaching 30 rep. (On SO only, since live updates are enabled for everyone on other sites). This would help to motivate new users to contribute and get 30 rep, and would also help avoid [confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322797/does-visibility-of-new-questions-depend-on-user-reputation). This was also briefly discussed in [the comments on Oded's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322824/4428462). Currently, "See vote counts" is also a privilege for performance reasons, and it *is* listed as such - so why not do the same thing with this one ?

Comment: It could still be listed but as a 1 rep privilege on other sites.

Comment: As I understood from participating in said discussion, the difference between "See vote counts" and "Live updates" is in the fact that "See vote counts" has an established threshold that's not expected to change and it's consistent across SE, while "Live updates" is something that can be tuned at any time and is not consistent. While I agree with the sentiment of this request, I also have to concede it's not _ready to be a privilege_ in the same sense that well-established "See vote counts" is.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not a fan of something NOT being explained ANYWHERE in the UI.

Comment: @Xan Rep for new tag privilege isn't consistent across SE Network either. Most graduated sites have it at 300, a few higher like 500, and SO 1500.

Comment: @DamianYerrick Thanks, I didn't know that (I'm only really active on SO)

Comment: @Xan Also, the threshold to participate on meta isn't consistent. On [PPCG](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/should-we-remove-the-reputation-requirement-for-answering-on-meta) (and probably others) you only need 1.

Comment: @Xan to me, this is the crux of the issue. This should be documents somewhere on the site, even if it's a line on the Help Center like 'Live page updates only become available after passing a certain reputation threshold, which varies between each site'

Comment: Absurd that this is not publicly documented.

Comment: [Exhibit A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327288/560648)

Comment: Maybe the Stack Overflow team will get to it in [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)?  Seriously though...any updates on the situation?